# SetSystemTime always add hour depending on Timezone

Tags: python, systemtime

```
import win32api
win32api.SetSystemTime (timetuple[0], timetuple[1], 
timetuple[6],timetuple[2], timetuple[3], timetuple[4], timetuple[5], 0)
```

I use this code to change system time on windows. But when i run this code it will automatically add +8 hours or depending on the timezone set in the computer. How will i set the time without it adding the timezone?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the MSDN:

> SetSystemTime function
>
> Sets the current system time and date. The system time is expressed in
>   Coordinated Universal Time (**UTC**).

You should use the [SetLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function if you want to use the computer's default timezone.